Canada re-entry for international student with study permit expiring 30th July
I'm an international student in Canada, and my study permit expires on July 30th. I have a conference scheduled for April 14th-20th, which means I'll be traveling outside of Canada and re-entering when I have about 3 months left on my permit.
Will I have trouble re-entering Canada with my study permit so close to expiration? Is there a requirement for study permits to be valid for at least 6 months upon re-entry? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

You will not be denied based on the days left on your study permit alone. You can enter on the last day of validity as long as you can satisfy the officer that you will leave Canada by the end of your authorized stay and that you continue to fulfill the conditions of your study permit (i.e., you are still studying or within 90 days of the end of the studies).
Note that if you visit somewhere other than the U.S. or St. Pierre and Miquelon, you must hold a valid temporary resident visa or an eTA (depending on your nationality) to seek entry into Canada.
Your study permit is not a visa or a document that would generally allow you in itself to seek admission into Canada or to board a commercial transport (even from the U.S.).
